# sql_safe_updates set to ON by default

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, environment-variables

This is fresh mysql install from Debian apt.

```
mysql> \s
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.47, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
..
Server version:         5.5.47-0+deb8u1-log (Debian)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
..
Note that you are running in safe_update_mode:
UPDATEs and DELETEs that don't use a key in the WHERE clause are not allowed.
```

This is how it's set:

```
mysql> show global variables like 'sql_safe_updates';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| sql_safe_updates | OFF   |
+------------------+-------+

mysql> show variables like 'sql_safe_updates';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| sql_safe_updates | ON    |
+------------------+-------+
```

There's no `sql_safe_updates` setting on any config file (`my.cnf` or `~/.my.cnf` etc.).

Why it's set to `ON` for my session (run `mysql` from root).

Comment: And no `init_command = SET sql_safe_updates = ON` ?

Answer (score 3):

From [here](https://zhefeng.wordpress.com/2009/03/11/disable-safe-update-mode/), you obtain the command to change the setting for `sql_safe_updates` (from the mysql client command line). It's fairly simple - `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;` (or `1`), though as you point out, it can't be modified in `my.ini` or `my.cnf`.

However, from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611685/run-sql-query-on-mysql-service-startup) on StackOverflow, you have a method to [run SQL (and server) commands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_init-file) on server startup.

Briefly, you create a file called (arbitrary) `<my_file_name>.sql` and put the command above setting the `sql_safe_updates` in that file.

Then, in the [mysqld] section of the `my.ini` (or `my.cnf`), you put the line

```
init-file="C:/xxx/yyy/<my_file_name>.sql"
```

To answer your **specific question**, there is a reason that the default is `ON`.

This is because many software developers are not very proficient in `SQL`. To compound this problem, many of them use frameworks which produce `SQL` which is (ahem...) not optimal. If one ran a command

```
DELETE FROM TABLE <no where clause>
```

on  a production system, this could cause havoc (and has done, judging by the number of posts here pleading for help with a deleted table).

Note: I tested this on Windows (don't have Linux up and running at the moment).